# How to get the web requesting domain user information in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

i am using windows 8 and its on the domain. using machine logged-in credential information i have to pass info which accessing the website in the same domain. (info like username of the client logged in machine.)

I tried with the code below:

```
string dsfsdf = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

unable to get the requestor info.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the user information from the WindowsIdentity object by doing the following

```
WindowsIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
```

You can find information on the object [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There is a property called Name that will give you the authenticated user name.

To get the clients machine name, you could use this:

```
string clientMachineName = Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName);
```

Hope that helps.